# Best way to print n number of characters based on the string length

Tags: c#, string

I'm writing a simple Console App in VS.

```csharp
Console.WriteLine("This Is Some Random Text");
Console.WriteLine("------------------------"); // Dashed line
```

Is there some more elegant solution to print dashed line, based on the string length of the above line? Solution that comes to my mind is:

```csharp
string text = "This Is Some Random Text"
Console.WriteLine(text);
string dashedLine = new String('-',text.Length);
Console.WriteLine(dashedLine);
```

Basically, I'm trying to minimize the initialization of a bunch of variables.

Comment: Your solution is fine, if you don't like the extra variable, just inline it: `Console.WriteLine(new String('-',text.Length));`

Answer (score 0):

I would create an extension method to make it a lot more streamlined and finger friendly :-)

```
public static class StringRepeaters {
    public static string Repeat(this string s, int n) => string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(s, n));
    public static string Repeat(this char ch, int n) => new string(ch, n);
}
```

You can use it just like this:

```
[Test]
public void UseStringRepeaters() {
    var s1 = "Hello!".Repeat(3);
    Assert.AreEqual("Hello!Hello!Hello!", s1);
    var s2 = '-'.Repeat(10);
    Assert.AreEqual("----------", s2);
}
```

We can build on this concept and create a method to print a dashed line beneath a text. The following will do this:

```
public static class StringRepeaters {
    public static string Dashed(this string s) 
        => $"{s}{Environment.NewLine}{'-'.Repeat(s.Length)}";
    public static string Repeat(this string s, int n) => string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(s, n));
    public static string Repeat(this char ch, int n) => new string(ch, n);
}
```

With this extension method your code can be simplified to just this:

```
Console.WriteLine("This Is Some Random Text".Dashed());
```